# In React (NextJS) Hyperlink not displaying in browser

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have below code in my react JS (nextjs). It works fine but only hyperlink is not displaying proper in browser.

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown'
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'
import { Parser } from 'html-to-react'
import { MathJax } from 'better-react-mathjax'

function FulltextRenderer({ content }) {
    return (
        <MathJax dynamic={true} renderMode="post">
            <ReactMarkdown
                source={content}
                escapeHtml={false}
                renderers={{
                    html: ({ value }) => {
                        // Use a consistent AST parser for both server/client.
                        // This will remove any inconsistencies or invalid HTML using a
                        // best guess (remove non-matching opening/closing tags).
                        const parser = new Parser()
                        try {
                            const element = parser.parse(value)

                            // Use the React DOM to render the sanitized HTML.
                            return (
                                <div
                                    // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-danger
                                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                                        __html: ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(element),
                                    }}
                                />
                            )
                        } catch (err) {
                            // In case of errors encountered by the parser, let's allow the DOM
                            // to make an attempt at parsing. This _may_ not be consistent with
                            // SSR vs Client.

                            // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-danger
                            return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: value }} />
                        }
                    },
                }}
            />
        </MathJax>
    )
}

FulltextRenderer.propTypes = {
    content: PropTypes.string,
}

FulltextRenderer.defaultProps = {
    content: '',
}

export default FulltextRenderer
```

When I inspect from chrome then in source code  tag is there. But still hyperlink is not rendering. I am not getting what is the issue. If anyone have any idea about this bug then please help me. Thank you very much in advance.